# Can a dataset parameter be used in reportviewer? If so, how?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I use VS2012 to develop reports. I have a report that has 4 parameters. Each of those parameters has a dataset associated with it. When I run the report in VS2012 Preview it works fine. After I have uploaded it to the server using a web framework it leaves any parameter using a dataset off the report entirely. So my assumption is that something is missing on the .aspx side that recognizes those parameter datasets...if it is even possible. Any direction/assistance appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you know its doing this? Does it not ask for parameter values when you run the report, or does it not apply the parameter values you select? The only way to know for sure is to profile the SQL and see if it is applying parameters or not.

Comment: When I open the URL, the object, in this case, a parameter dropdown associated with a dataset doesn't even display on the screen. Where as other non-dataset parameters do. I had forgotten to check profiler; I will need to verify. Thanks.

Comment: In the report viewer control in your aspx page. There is a property called ShowParameterPrompt. Set that to True.

Comment: Apologies for getting back so late. I did run the SQL profiler and the  dropdown associated with a dataset does not show in profiler. 

Regarding the ShowParameterPrompt would that be placed within a tag like below?

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="true" OnDrillthrough="xxx" OnReportError="xxx" ViewStateMode="Enabled" PageCountMode="Actual" ShowPrintButton="true"  DocumentMapWidth="0"  ShowParameterPrompt="true" ShowDocumentMapButton="true" ProcessingMode="Local" Height="700px" Width="800px" Visible="true">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>